# How to submit POST request data to a TemplateView function?

Tags: django-forms, django-views

I want to do a POST request from a form in a django template and use the posted values in a TemplateView to change which data is sent to the template. The only thing that doesn't work is using the posted values in a separate function in the View.

To achieve the above mentioned goals I created a TemplateView:

```
class SearchView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "pages/home.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        for key in request.POST:
            print(key)
            value = request.POST[key]
            print(value)
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            context = super(SearchView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

All values of the submitted form get printed including the CSRF middleware token.

This is my SearchForm:

```
class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    field1 = forms.CharField(label='field1 label', max_length=25)
    field2 = forms.CharField(label='field2 label', max_length=25)
```

In the View I also created a function called search_data:

```
def search_data(self):
    for key in self.request.POST:
    print(key)
    value = self.request.POST[key]
    print(value)
```

This function is called in javascript via a template with

```
{{ view.search_data }}
```

Later on in this function I am using the formdata for some calculations and send it back to the template. The submission to the template works fine via the function `mark_safe()`.

As I mentioned I use a CSRF middleware token via `{% csrf_token %}` in my `<form>` in the template.

The problem is that the form values are empty when I try to access/print them in the post request of the `search_data()` function.

The weird thing is when I delete field2 in my SearchForm the values of field1 can be accessed in the `search_data()` function. I tried to change the formfields and found out that this works when the SearchForm only has 1 field. Whenever I have more than 1 field in my SearchForm I can't access the values after the `render()` method.

Is there anything wrong with my return statement in the SearchView? I tried out the deprecated version `render_to_response()` as well, but as expected this didn't change anything.

I also tried out `return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})`, but then the `search_data` function does not get called at all.

Please tell me if you need any further information.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are interested I solved the problem by writing the POST request values to the session in my `post()` function:

```
for key in request.POST:
    keys.append(key)
    values.append(request.POST[key])
request.session['keys'] = keys
request.session['values'] = values
```

Now I am able to access these in my `search_data()` function by:

```
for value in self.request.session['values']
    print(value)
for key in self.request.session['keys']
    print(key)
```